# Cannot create ScalaDoc link for overloaded method

Tags: scala, overloading, scaladoc

I am running into a problem with ScalaDoc not accepting a method link when using overloading.

A standalone example: File `project/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.2
```

File `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
```

File `src/main/scala/Foo.scala`:

```
package foobar

/** @see [[Bar#foo]]
  * @see [[Bar#bar]]
  */
case class Foo()

abstract class Bar {
  def foo: Int

  def bar: Foo
  def bar(x: Option[Int]): Foo
}
```

When I run `sbt doc`, the `[[Bar#foo]]` link is fine, but the `[[Bar#bar]]` link is not accepted:

```
[warn] .../src/main/scala/Foo.scala:3: The link target "Bar#bar" is ambiguous. 
       Several members fit the target:
[warn] (x: Option[Int]): foobar.Foo in class Bar [chosen]
[warn] : foobar.Foo in class Bar
[warn] 
[warn] 
[warn] Quick crash course on using Scaladoc links
[warn] ==========================================
[warn] Disambiguating terms and types: Prefix terms with '$' and types with '!' in case both names are in use:
[warn]  - [[scala.collection.immutable.List!.apply class List's apply method]] and
[warn]  - [[scala.collection.immutable.List$.apply object List's apply method]]
[warn] Disambiguating overloaded members: If a term is overloaded, you can indicate the first part of its signature followed by *:
[warn]  - [[[scala.collection.immutable.List$.fill[A](Int)(⇒A):List[A]* Fill with a single parameter]]]
[warn]  - [[[scala.collection.immutable.List$.fill[A](Int,Int)(⇒A):List[List[A]]* Fill with a two parameters]]]
[warn] Notes:
[warn]  - you can use any number of matching square brackets to avoid interference with the signature
[warn]  - you can use \\. to escape dots in prefixes (don't forget to use * at the end to match the signature!)
[warn]  - you can use \\# to escape hashes, otherwise they will be considered as delimiters, like dots.
[warn] /** @see [[Bar#foo]]
[warn] ^
[warn] one warning found
```

So using the "crash course", I tried all sorts of things, e.g.

```
[[Bar#bar:Foo*]]
[[Bar!.bar:Foo*]]
[[foobar.Bar!.bar:foobar.Foo*]]
```

None of this works. Neither using the other overloaded variant:

```
[[Bar#bar(Option[Int])]]
[[Bar#bar(Option[Int]):Foo]]
[[Bar!.bar(Option[Int]):Foo*]]
```

So either (like always...) scala-doc is totally broken, or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me. Use fully qualified argument and return types, where dots have been prefixed by `\`.

```
[[Bar#bar:foobar\.Foo* The first bar method without argument]]
[[Bar#bar(x:Option[Int]):foobar\.Foo* The second bar method with argument]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with:

```
package foobar

/** @see [[Bar#foo]]
  * @see [[Bar!.bar*]]
  * @see [[[Bar!.bar(x:Option[Int])*]]]
  */
case class Foo()

abstract class Bar {
  def foo: Int

  def bar: Foo
  def bar(x: Option[Int]): Foo
}
```

And although I get the same warning, the docs are generated with links to both bar methods.

So I guess scala-doc is not *totally* broken... just a little annoying.